# Get value from fields with same class, add to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a dynamic list of textboxes that have all the same class, like so:

```
<input type="text" id="value1" class="list-value" />
<input type="text" id="value2" class="list-value" />
<input type="text" id="value3" class="list-value" />
<input type="text" id="value4" class="list-value" />
```

So when a link is clicked, I need the values from all those textboxes to be loaded into an array:

```
$('a#link').click(function() {
    //add to array here
});
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var values = $('.list-value').map(function() { return this.value; }).get();
```

The ".map()" method will iterate through the list of elements like ".each()", but it takes the return value and accumulates an array. The final ".get()" is necessary to get a "raw" array instead of a jQuery object (a wrapper around the array), but that's not always necessary; it depends on what you want to do with the result.